# Extract Value from Promise

Tags: javascript, promise

Trying to extract from a promise, see below. The value that I'm trying to extract is the "mObjectUUID:".

Able to pull back the promise through "resolveProductNodes().then()" but unsure then how to extract the ID. Can you help?

```
Promise {<fulfilled>: Array(1)}
[[Prototype]]
: 
Promise
catch
: 
ƒ catch()
constructor
: 
ƒ Promise()
finally
: 
ƒ finally()
then
: 
ƒ then()
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag)
: 
"Promise"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
[[PromiseState]]
: 
"fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]
: 
Array(1)
0
: 
S {mObjectId: 1, mObjectUUID: 'e4702625-15ce-a6c8-b88e-b790e7e47224', mMessageHandlers: {…}, mComponents: Array(7), mRenderObject: h, …}
length
: 
1
[[Prototype]]
: 
Array(0)
```

I tried "resolveProductNodes().then()" but then unsure how to extract the ID. Can you help?

Comment: The argument to the `.then()` callback is whatever the promises's function passed when it called `resolve()`.

Answer (score 0):

The `.then()` callback function receives the object as its argument. You can then extract properties from that.

It looks like the resolved value is an array, you need to index it.

```
resolveProductNodes().then(res => console.log(res[0].mObjectUUID));
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar. Ran the code in the console however it's coming back undefined. Is there anything else I should be doing?

Comment: Please post a [mre] that shows the promise code. It's hard to tell what's really going on from the output you showed.

Comment: Ran the code:
window.expivi.resolveProductNodes().then(res => console.log(res.mObjectUUID));


Output is:


undefined 
Promise {<fulfilled>: undefined}
[[Prototype]] : Promise
[[PromiseState]] : "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]] : undefined

Comment: I need to see the code for `resolveProductNodes()` to see how it calls `resolve()`

Comment: Try `res[0].mObjectUUID`. It looks like the value is an array.

Comment: Not quite. Got the error message:

Uncaught ReferenceError: resolveProductNodes is not defined at <anonymous>:1:1

Comment: If the function isn't defined, that's a completely different problem.